# tkinters entry widget effect on canvas when clicking

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

When an entry widget is on the canvas and its clicked then the window does an effect that I would like to avoid.
Heres an example so you can see what im saying:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master, x, y):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=x, height=y)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.canvas)
        p0x, p0y = x/2, y/2
        self.canvas.create_window(p0x, p0y, anchor="center", window=self.entry)


xroot = 1080
yroot = 720

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root, xroot, yroot)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the thin border around the canvas?

Comment: Yes, the border around the canvas that appears when clicking